# Check whether the number of database rows changed compared to last time the PHP script is run?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm a bit stuck on how to program this: here's what I'm trying to do - I'm writing a simple chat application. There are two parts:

1.The send message part - where a message is typed into the textarea and stored into the database  (I implemented this with jQuery AJAX)

**Database: There are two columns in the database, Date and Message

2.The receive message part - where new updates from the server are updated on the page without refreshing the page (I implemented this with HTML 5 SSE).

At a higher level, here's the main problem: I don't know how to write a condition - the condition being the code within the IF block running ONLY when the database has been updated compared to last time the even was fired - in other words, it should update when there is a new message only ONCE, instead of what you get below:

[image: Without if condition]

Here's the two code pages (I think it's better to include it all or else the context is a bit vague):

**Quick summary:**

**chat.php** - the main chat interface

**messaging.php** - the send button on the chat redirects here for handling

**get_message.php** - listens in on new messages and displays it in AJAX style

**chat.php**

```
<!-- display window -->
<div class = "message-window" id = "message-window">
    Chat starts
</div>

<!-- listens in to new server updates and updates with new messages -->
<script>
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("get_message.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        document.getElementById("message-window").innerHTML+=event.data + "<br>";
    };
} else {    
       document.getElementById("message-window").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}
</script>

<!-- comopse message area -->
<div class = "send-wrapper">
    <textarea id = "compose"></textarea>
    <button type = "button" id = "send">Send</button>
</div>

<!-- event handler for click button to pass along data on the page -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#send").on('click', function() {
    $.post(
        // file
        "messaging.php", 
        // data
        {
            // date: Date.toLocaleString(),
            message: $("#compose").val()
        },
        // function after success
        function(data, status) {
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            var singleMessageContent = $("#compose").val();
            $("#message-window").html(
                $("#message-window").html() + "<br />" + singleMessageContent
        );
    });
 });
 });
 </script>
```

**get_message.php**

```
<?php
// get_message.php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

echo "retry: 1000\n";


// Create connection
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'button');

// If number of rows changed from last retry

    IF BLOCK (...)

// Get the most recent row
$query = "SELECT message FROM messages ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

// echo the message field
$most_recent_row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

echo "data: {$most_recent_row[0]}\n\n";

    IF BLOCK (...)

flush();

?>
```

As you can see, what I'm stuck on is the if block - the event is fired every time by the EventSource object on chat.php (this is correct I presume?), so how do I compare the database in question AT DIFFERENT times the event was fired? I need this because I'd like to write this such that messages show ONLY when the database is updated.

```
if(current_database_rows != old_database_rows)
```

Here are my thoughts:

Something to do with a global variable? In terms of setting the global variable to count the number of rows in the database at the end of each execution of the php code, run mysqli_num_rows($result), and compare to this variable. My question is - how would you create this "shared" variable that doesn't lose its value in between firing events?

If you can fill me in on a possible condition, or an alternative solution, or other ideas, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Keep an ID being the ID of the last message, and keep requesting where `id > last_max_id`. That way you only get new rows. When you return the new messages you should also return a new max ID and save this for the next request.

Comment: h2ooooooo is correct -- don't overthink it!

Comment: you can also do a count() of the rows if you do not want to change the table structure and somewhere store the count (maybe send it along into the chat, in a hidden field, and have ajax send it back to compare or something)

Comment: I would add a 'read' boolean field to the table, and mark it true when you retrieve it. SELECT * ... WHERE read = 0

Comment: @user574632 I just thought of the exact same thing in the shower! Thanks! :) Wished people would actually answer this so I can mark this answered:)

Comment: @h2ooooooo Again, the question might have been a bit convoluted, but that's the problem - I don't know HOW to pass a variable with the EventObject - I tried programming it in jQuery, but I have the feeling that it went horribly wrong. I'll check my syntax next time to see if I can add in the .post method as an atlernative solution.

Comment: @iMakeWebsites That's a nice idea too! I didn't think of that - neat solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing the date(hopefully time?) that a message is sent, you could return the time of the last chat message then keeping sending back that updated value to your query(through ajax) to only receive chat past that time.

Comment: An incrementing ID is way better. What if I loaded the site `2014-05-22 16:57:03,023` and someone posted `2014-05-22 16:57:03,155`? I wouldn't see it, then.

Answer (score 0):

Upon the ideas that were mentioned by the folks kind enough to answer, the simplest way is to keep an additional field in the database when a message is added as a record. This shows whether the message has already been retrieved or not. Once it has, it's set to true, bounced back to the jQuery in chat.php to handle, and voila, it's solved. :) Thanks guys!